# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency in android studio 3.4

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I was using android studio 3.3 and everything worked fine. But today after updating to 3.4 I get these errors. It seems trouble originates with androidX dependencies. It also happens in my two different projects which depends on androidX.

I have tried the following:

1.Clean and rebuild my project

2.Invalidate the cache and restart.

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

My build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
apply plugin: 'com.apollographql.android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "********"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    //Apollo
    implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:1.0.0-alpha5'
    implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-http-cache:1.0.0-alpha5'
    implementation "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-coroutine-support:1.0.0-alpha5"

    //okhttp3
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'

    //Anko
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$anko_version"

    //Dependency injection
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'

    //Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha06"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:2.1.0-alpha04"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha06"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha04"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:2.1.0"

    //Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2'

    //Navigation
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0"

    //Fresco - Image Loader.
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.12.1'

    //Maps and Location
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0"

    //Preference
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0"

    //Multidex
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    //Google Ads
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'

    //ImagePicker.
    implementation 'com.github.nguyenhoanglam:ImagePicker:1.3.1'
}
```

build.gradle project level

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        anko_version = '0.10.8'
        kotlin_version = '1.3.30'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
        classpath 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { //For coroutine support
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/apollographql/android'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How can I solve it

Comment: This could be happen due to many issue. 1. Check your network config, maybe your network are under the proxy configuration 2. Open new project not your existing one, then everything is compiled correctly then configure your old projects based on successfully build project 3. Disable offline if enabled. 4. Good network connection may be also answer. try them one by one. Since it happens to me a lot and one of above method always helped me. BWT do not forget "SYNC Project" after each step

Comment: you have to add `android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true` these rules in gradle.properties file in your project

Comment: I have the same issues when trying to convert old style instant app to new dynamic modules. it happens in the installed-feature.  must be bug in gradle. shitty implementation it is

Comment: @GillisHaasnoot solved it?

Comment: Yes, i am a little further. 
My issue was that i was not including the core android x library in the dynamic module where i got the errors.
So i created a seperate "Library" (not a dynamic-module), where I have all the core dependencies like:
androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha05
androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha07
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8
etc. I include that library in all my dynamic modules.
Now it builds at least. Of course i am facing a new set of completely different issues now which i have to resolve :)

Comment: I am having the same issue when upgrading to gradle 5.1.1. Clearing cache does not work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved my problem by reverting **distributionUrl** in **gradle-wrapper.properties**

from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

back to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

And also reverting gradle dependency in build.gradle from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
```

back to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

And now my project is fine.

Comment: But did you able to solve the problem without downgrading?

Comment: @Dr.jacky I tried a lot and failed. I am waiting for next gradle release may this one got some bugs!

Comment: I'm waiting for a reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55782093/error-minimum-supported-gradle-version-is-5-1-1-current-version-is-4-4-1-afte/55782182#comment98721863_55782182

Comment: Happened Same thing to me. Got Fixed by updating every library into their latest version

Answer (score 0):

Add following in your app module dependency list.

```
implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: Thanks for response.I added those dependencies but still I face the same problem.