# Error "Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.1.1. Current version is 4.4.1" after update android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I updated android studio from 3.3 to 3.4 version and after install and do `./gradlew lint` I am getting the next error:

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 6.0.

Then I use the next command to get more details:

```
  ./gradlwe build --warning-mode=all
```

And I get the next message:

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>
> > Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.1.1. Current version is 4.4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in .gradle/daemon/4.4.1/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
> >     to gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

And when I edited my gradle-wrapper.properties, I see that the changes were already done, I.E. the version of the `distributionUrl` already was gradle-5.1.1.-all.zip

Any idea that how can resolve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve this dropping the folders of the oldest version in `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists` and leave only the `gradle-5.1.1-all`

Comment: hi, I have the same problem, could you please explain how do you fix it? I do not see this location about you speak, thanks.

Comment: Hello, I am using ubuntu 18.04, then in my home folder, you can access to this folder with this `cd ~` I had, a folder with name `.gradle` and inside this wrapper and inside this dist, and inside this a lot of gradle* folder, I droped all folders and I leave only the gradle-5.1.1-all folder

I think that if you delete directly with `rm -rf ~/.gradle/wrapper/dist/*` all gradle versions too

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES Are you using kotlin? If yes, what version are you using? Cause I have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781955/error-unable-to-resolve-dependency-in-android-studio-3-4

Comment: No I am using Java

Comment: @MarkWalczak awesome...that fixed my problem...android studio showed 5.1.1 and when i opened the file it showd 4.x..

Comment: I'm using kotlin. And after deleting all of them, they are recreating those gradle files

Comment: still in that issue.

Comment: @Singorenko On a Mac, ~ means the home folder. In Terminal enter `cd ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists` then `ls` to see the content

Comment: Delete everything in the ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists folder than restart Android Studio and lunch app. It will automatically get the right gradle files

Comment: this solution worked for me with flutter, but a few days later I had to do it again :/

Answer (score 90):

You could just edit YOUR_APPLICATION_FOLDER/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and change the last line to: 
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip`
Android Studio will download necessary library.

Comment: after apply this modification and then run ionic cordova --release android this change reverted back automatically to v4

Comment: for me gradle version required was 5.4.1 and changed it in the gradle-wrapper.properties, but still it shows the same error. Any help will be thankfull

Comment: i tried above code and but after build android from cli all changes are reset can you tell me sir whats the issue?

Comment: In flutter, the location should be` <app dir>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Answer (score 33):

This was my solution.

```
My_project
  /gradle
  /wrapper
  /gradle-wrapper.properties
```

Modify this line with the Gradle 5.1.1

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Comment: This didn't work! `flutter run` end with build failure

Comment: Try `flutter clean`

Comment: `flutter clean` also didn't help.
Anyways, instead of updating this manually, I have done this via Android Studio, and that worked

Comment: i tried above code and but after build android from cli all changes are reset can you tell me sir whats the issue?

Answer (score 11):

In my case, gradle failed to download the version I specified though I tried all previous solutions.

Apparently, I was opening my project by selecting "MyProject/App" directory. Gradle successfully updated when I opened the same project by selecting the "MyProject" folder.

Answer (score 9):

1. Check your full project and find all "Gradle-wrapper.properties" files. If your project has multiple modules then there are chances of having multiple. and set -

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

2. Gradle sync
3. If not done then invalidate the cache and restart the project.
4. Still not working then go to your root directory on Linux and find .gradle folder. Delete it and restart the android studio.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Ubuntu and all above answers didn't solve your problem try to upgrade gradle on your Ubuntu with this commands from this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/975018/714791

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade gradle
```

It will help I hope

Answer (score 5):

I resolved by two below steps.

1. delete gradle folder
2. check your classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:{$gradleVersion}

My gradleVersion is 3.5.3.

Answer (score 4):

those who are still facing issue with Cordova/Ionic, this is due to `CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL` which is being checked at `platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js`

set `CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL` to desired distributional

for MacOs

```
export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by changing the `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` in `gradle/wrapper`, not `gradle.properties`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's your gradle environment variable.
execute 'gradle -v'
Check that the gradle version of the project matches the gradle environment variable version

Comment: Thank you, this was my case and I used sdkman to install the version I wanted, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's very important to **mention which IDE you're using** and what are the configurations.
What made me upset was, I had a setting in gradle-wrapper.properties file which was "ignored" to my mind.

**I've found the settings in the IDEA application settings**, there:
[image]

**and then selecting:**

[image]
and everything works as expected.

Deleting 'all other' locally cached versions can never be the right solution ;)

**Good luck!**

Answer (score 2):

My app is using Cordova v9.0.0

**distributionUrl** is set at platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\ProjectBuilder.js

You can set **distributionUrl** from the command line with

```
set CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL="https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-[version]-all.zip"
```

Replace [version] with your preference

Answer (score 1):

it solved for me
get the flutter SDK directory

this is my flutter Sdk 
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity_macos-0.1.0+2\android\gradle\wrapper

change gradle-wrapper.properties

Modify this line with the Gradle 5.1.1

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error: Error **"Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.1.1. Current version is 5.1.1"** but when I opened the gradle.properties and I found this *"distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip"*  which was correct but wasn't working. To solve this, I deleted the ".gradle" file in the explorer, reopened the app and found out the **distributionUrl** had change to *5.2.2-all.zip* in gradle.properties; I then edited to *6.1.1-all.zip* and sync and everything worked like a charm. I hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download manually Gradle-5.1.1 from https://gradle.org/releases then go to file/project structure/project and put the new version in gradle version. (You can also use this link - jenv.io/candidate/gradle)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem after migrating from `android.support` library to `androidx` where junit library start with ***androidTestImplementation*** and not 
***testImplementation***.

So i changed

```
testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"
```

to

```
androidTestImplementation androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0-beta01
```

or

```
androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"
```

Remember to append `android` before testImplementation

Answer (score 0):

also, try removing all older/unwanted versions of gradle using:
cd usr/local/Cellar/gradle/

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to run the gradle wrapper in your project: https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Delete gradle folder from your project directory as well as from the app directory.

restart Adroid studio and resync gradle.

it will solve your problem. If not you might be opened the project yourproject/app. close Android studio and import your project after selecting yourproject. Then resync gradle. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows 10:**

Go to `C:\Users\<user-name>\.gradle\wrapper\dists` and delete everything there. Android studio will download the appropriate version afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still searching for a solution after trying literally everything, here's what worked for me.

In the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, my `image:` key was outdated and was writing in the script that Gradle was set to 5.1.1 even though everything in my Android Studio was 7.0.2. After talking to the guy who wrote the image script, I just had to increment the version of that.

https://forum.gitlab.com/t/set-specific-version-of-gradle-for-ci-build/41716/4

Answer (score 0):

This error was solved by restarting Android Studio.