# "Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.1.1. Current version is 5.4.1." but gradle-wrapper.properties has 6.1.1

Tags: android, gradle

Syncing gradle gives me this error:

Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.1.1. Current version is 5.4.1.

```
Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project
Open Gradle wrapper properties
Gradle settings
```

The `Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project` option does nothing.

Here is my `gradle.wrapper.properties` file:

```
#Wed Aug 19 16:26:03 IST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

It has the right version yet I get `Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.1.1. Current version is 5.4.1.`

I'm on Mac OS 10.15.5 and Android Studio 4.0.1.

Comment: Try restarting with clear cache and then build the gradle. It might help.

Answer (score 5):

This image helps, in https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

[image: iii]

---

eg:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1.2-bin.zip
```

in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

maps

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1"
```

in `build.gradle`

---

you need to make the relationship correct.

Answer (score 1):

Update your gradle with:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 6.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble this same. [This also not work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55782093/error-minimum-supported-gradle-version-is-5-1-1-current-version-is-4-4-1-afte)

Here's how I fixed it

1. Download desired gradle release from [Gradle official](https://gradle.org/releases/)  Create
2. New folder (Gradle) under C:\Gradle. Extract downloaded release here
3. Goto file->setting->Build, Execution, Deployment->**Gradle**
4. Use Gradle From **Specified Location** instead gradle.wrapper
5. Android Studio will auto-detect the path; if not choose manually
6. Sync project with Gradle file