# how to solve this problem in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 5 s 654 ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\CulturelWordsGame\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
> Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.5-rc-1. Current version is 6.1.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-6.5-rc-1-all.zip

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Gradle wrapper version to 6.5-rc-1 (At least). Check gradle-wrapper.properties file in your project

Comment: how to upgrade it? I tried from project structure but nothing worked.

Comment: Open Android Studio->File->Project structure, in Project section select the Gradle Version

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `gradle-wrapper.properties` in the gradle folder (not .gradle), you can find the line `distributionUrl=...`

Change this to:

`distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip`

And sync your project again.

*I'm currently also having this problem. The last time I changed the above line it worked, but now it is stuck with 6.1.1 even though I changed this line. I will keep you updated if the above does not work.*

You can also see this question, which is similar:
[Error "Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.1.1. Current version is 4.4.1" after update android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55782093/error-minimum-supported-gradle-version-is-5-1-1-current-version-is-4-4-1-afte)

UPDATE:

You can also change:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:...'`

to

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'`

because [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) you can see that the plugin version of 4.1.0+ needs gradle 6.5+ so you could also downgrade the plugin version as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error. Fixed it by:

1. open **build.gradle**(project) file, dependency part
2. add **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'**
3. open **gradle-wrapper.properties**
4. change distributionUrl to **https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip**

It solved my problem I hope solve yours too.